# "ihr" is referring to which noun

Tags: pronoun

I was given the following paragraph:

> Das Speichern und das Veröffentlichen von Musik sind heute mit der MP3 Technik möglich. Diese Technik, mit der man Musik über das Internet senden kann, ist eine Entwicklung aus Erlangen, wurde aber zuerst in Japan produziert. Die Technologie ist besonders attraktiv für Musikfans, weil man mit ihr viele Lieder auf einem kleinen Chip speichern kann. Der Qualitätsverlust ist dabei sehr gering. Mit **ihr** kann man auch unterwegs Musik hören, zum Beispiel vom Handy.

But I was struggling to understand what "ihr" was referring to.

When reading previous articles, I remember that a possessive adjectives can be used to refer to an article / object that is **[feminine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ihr)** (i.e. "ihr" means "it") but I couldn't find any nouns that were feminine. I tried:

- der MP3 (masc.)
- Chip (masc.)

so what is "ihr" referring to in this context?

Comment: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/MP3) disagrees and specifies *MP3* as neuter - of course this does not invalidate the question.

Answer (score 8):

"Ihr" refers to "die Technologie"

The last sentence could be rewritten as:

> Mit dieser Technologie kann man auch unterwegs Musik hören, zum Beispiel vom Handy